# T-SQL: how to sort table rows based on 2 columns

Tags: t-sql, sorting, rows, multiple-columns

I'm quite stuck with this problem for sometime now..

How do I sort column A depending on the contents of Column B?

I have this sample:

```
ID  count   columnA     ColumnB
-----------------------------------
12  1      A         B
13  2      C         D
14  3      B         C
```

I want to sort it like this:

```
ID  count   ColumnA     ColumnB
-----------------------------------
12  1   A       B
14  3   B       C
13  2   C       D
```

so I need to sort the rows if the previous row of `ColumnB` = the next row of `ColumnA`

I'm thinking a loop? but can't quite imagine how it will work...

I was thinking it will go like this (maybe)

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB
FROM 
    TableA WITH a (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN 
    TableA b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.counts = b.counts
WHERE
    a.columnB = b.ColumnA
```

the above code isn't working though and I was thinking more on the lines of...

```
DECLARE @counts int = 1
DECLARE @done int = 0

--WHILE @done = 0
BEGIN

SELECT 
    a.ID, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB
FROM 
    TableA WITH a (NOLOCK)  
LEFT JOIN 
    TableA b WITH (NOLOCK)  ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.counts = @counts
WHERE 
    a.columnB = b.ColumnA

set @count = @count +1
END
```

If this was a C code, would be easier for me but T-SQL's syntax is making it a bit harder for a noobie like me.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: sample code

```
drop table tablea
create table TableA(
id int,
colA varchar(10),
colb varchar(10),
counts int
)

insert INTO TableA
(id, cola, colb, counts)
select 12, 'Bad', 'Cat', 3

insert INTO TableA
(id, cola, colb, counts)
select 13, 'Apple', 'Bad', 1

insert INTO TableA
(id, cola, colb, counts)
select 14, 'Cat', 'Dog', 2

select * FROM TableA

SELECT a.ID, a.ColA, a.ColB
FROM TableA a WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN TableA b WITH (NOLOCK) 
     ON a.ID = b.ID
Where a.colB = b.ColA
ORDER BY a.ColA ASC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When adding code or tabular data, please use 4-space indentation. You can automatically add the indentation by selecting the corresponding text and either clicking the `{}` button on the toolbar or pressing the `Ctrl+K` shortcut. Thank you!

Comment: More help on formatting: [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If so, is the version 2005+?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `ORDER BY` clause

```
-- SELECT a.ID, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB
-- FROM TableA WITH a (NOLOCK) 
--        LEFT JOIN TableA b WITH (NOLOCK) 
--            ON a.ID = b.ID
--               and a.counts = b.counts
-- Where a.columnB = b.ColumnA
ORDER BY a.ColumnA ASC
```

Comment: But what if the column's for Column A and Column B are actual words?

Like:
ID  counts Column A    ColumnB

12    1     HEY         YAY

14    3     BAY         DAY

13    2     YAY         BAY

so I want it to be

ID  counts Column A    ColumnB

12    1     HEY         YAY

13    2     YAY         BAY

14    3     BAY         DAY

Comment: the same. the server sorts it for you. try it :D

Comment: wow you're right! Although 1 more question, I seem to be getting only 2 rows> The last row which is supposed to be contain the last order is missing? D:

Comment: what do you mean missing? maybe it has something to do with your query. can you atleast include it on your question (*the query you used*)? :D

Comment: the query was: 
-- SELECT a.ID, a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB, b.ColumnA, b.ColumnB

-- FROM TableA WITH a (NOLOCK) 

--        LEFT JOIN TableA b WITH (NOLOCK) 

--            ON a.ID = b.ID

-- Where a.columnB = b.ColumnA

--ORDER BY a.ColumnA ASC


and what I got was kinda like this:
ID    a.ColumnA     a.ColumnB     b.ColumnA    b.ColumnB
12       A             B             B             C
14       B             C             C             D

the C and D on b.columnA and b.ColumnB became a row instead of column? :O

Comment: i added a sample script that I made :x

Comment: You can even sort by two columns, as `ORDER BY a.ColumnA ASC,  a.ColumnB ASC` this sorts first by `columnA`, then by `columnB`.

Comment: my problem now is... instead of seeing 3 original rows, I'm seeing only 2 rows now.. Please check the image -> http://tinypic.com/r/nzot52/6

I'm thinking this happens because of the condition:
where a.colb = b.cola

Comment: @CrissNautilus I was wondering why you joins your table to itself. Isn't is as simple as sthis? [SQLFiddle Demo (Click Here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d969/2)

Comment: because in reality, the value in the columns are not arranged in alphabetical order like my sample. Take this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5eb65/1

when I tried to jumble the words it, won't work anymore

It's supposed to be: Dog Apple, Apple Day, Day Mad

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need. Sometimes you have to think simple

```
select * from table A
order by columnA asc
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The sort order required depends on the relationship between columnA and columnB